# writing a .gml (or easy for mathematica to read) file from python array

Tags: python, arrays, network-programming, wolfram-mathematica

I have a sizable array (8000ish entires) in python which is the edge list of a graph. part of the array looks like:

```
... [' Tulane-B (Tulane (Bacchus)) ', ' Florida Tech (Florida Tech) '],
[' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' San Jose State (Megabyte) '],
[' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' Duke (Brimstone) '],
[' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' Oregon State (Beavers) '],...
```

The string pairs pairs of vertices which have an edge between them.

Is there a efficient way to import this array into mathematica, so that it can read it? I know mathematica strings are surrounded by `{`. Can I just export this array in a different format out of python, or do I have to go in an re-parse the thing as a string?
Where my code looks like:

```
print('{', end = '')
for edge in named_edgelist: 
        print('{' + '\"' + edge[0] +'\"' +  ", " +'\"'  + edge[1] + '\"' + '},', end ='')
print('}',end = '')
```

second to last print call makes an extra comma, but i'm not worrying about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add your expected output to your question, since not all Python coders know Mathematica. I assume you want something like `{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}}` etc. You can easily do this with string formatting. So you should make an attempt to code this yourself and paste your code attempt into the question.

Comment: Your example is the format I did instead, should have wrote that down. The point of the question though is for educational purposes is there an easier way to do this. I know I can do the string formatting easily, but to save future time I am wondering if their is a more efficient way.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this with string formatting, so it's a bit hard to suggest a more efficient way than what you're currently doing if we can't actually see what you're currently doing.

Comment: Thanks for adding that info. Can you guarantee that the strings will _never_ contain any double-quote characters? Can they contain square brackets? It looks like you're using Python 3, is that correct?

Comment: I am using python3 my output, has no brackets and it should not have any. There are no double quotes.

Comment: BTW, I just added a version that puts each row onto a separate line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is clean, i.e., it contains no double-quotes or square brackets we can use the [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method to translate Python's native string representation of the list into Mathematica format.

To use `str.translate` we first need to construct a translation table, using the [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) method.

```
data = [
    [' Tulane-B (Tulane (Bacchus)) ', ' Florida Tech (Florida Tech) '],
    [' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' San Jose State (Megabyte) '],
    [' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' Duke (Brimstone) '],
    [' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' Oregon State (Beavers) '],
]

trans = str.maketrans("'[]", '"{}')
s = str(data).translate(trans)
print(s)
```

**output**

```
{{" Tulane-B (Tulane (Bacchus)) ", " Florida Tech (Florida Tech) "}, {" Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ", " San Jose State (Megabyte) "}, {" Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ", " Duke (Brimstone) "}, {" Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ", " Oregon State (Beavers) "}}
```

This is faster than using Python loops with Python string formatting, since almost all the work is being done by code that's written in C, so it runs at C speed.

---

FWIW, this can also be done in Python 2, with a minor change. In Python 2, there's no `str.maketrans` method. Instead, you need to use the [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) helper function.

---

If you'd like each row to be on a separate line you'll need to pre-process each row. This will necessarily be a little slower, but the speed difference will be hardly noticeable with 8000 rows.

```
data = [
    [' Tulane-B (Tulane (Bacchus)) ', ' Florida Tech (Florida Tech) '],
    [' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' San Jose State (Megabyte) '],
    [' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' Duke (Brimstone) '],
    [' Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ', ' Oregon State (Beavers) '],
]

# Convert data to strings with each row on a separate line
s = '[\n    ' + ',\n    '.join([str(row) for row in data]) + '\n]'

trans = str.maketrans("'[]", '"{}')
s = s.translate(trans)
print(s)
```

**output**

```
{
    {" Tulane-B (Tulane (Bacchus)) ", " Florida Tech (Florida Tech) "},
    {" Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ", " San Jose State (Megabyte) "},
    {" Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ", " Duke (Brimstone) "},
    {" Stanford-B (Stanford Prison Experiment) ", " Oregon State (Beavers) "}
}
```